# Segmentation fault with concatenation of two strings

Tags: c

I'm trying to build alphanumeric strings consisting of 3 initial letters and 3 final numbers and save them in a *.txt* file. I wrote this:

```
int i = 0,          
    j = 0;     
char name_cpu[8],
     array_numbers_final[8],    
     array_letters[27] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYVZ",
     array_numbers[10] = "123456789";


/* Generator data */
  for(i = 0; i < number_cpu; i++)
  { 
      for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      name_cpu[j] = array_letters[rand() % (sizeof(array_letters)-1)];
      array_numbers_final[j] = array_numbers[rand() % (sizeof(array_numbers)-1)];
    }

    strcat(name_cpu, array_numbers_final);
    fprintf(list_cpu, "%s \n", name_cpu);
  }
```

The problem is that at the first external *for* loop it correctly prints a string of the form "AAA000". At the second for loop it goes in segmentation fault. Can anyone tell me what and where I am doing wrong?

EDIT:
A minimal reproducible example is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void){

  FILE *list_cpu = NULL;
  int i = 0,
  number_cpu = 3,    
  j = 0;     
  char name_cpu[8] = {0},
  array_numbers_final[8] = {0},    
  array_letters[27] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYVZ",
  array_numbers[10] = "123456789";
        
  list_cpu = fopen("list_cpu.txt", "w");  
        
        
  /* Generator data */
  for(i = 0; i < number_cpu; i++)
  { 
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      name_cpu[j] = array_letters[rand() % (sizeof(array_letters)-1)];
      array_numbers_final[j] = array_numbers[rand() % (sizeof(array_numbers)-1)];
  }
   strcat(name_cpu, array_numbers_final);
   fprintf(list_cpu, "%s \n", name_cpu);
  }
  fclose(list_cpu);

return(0);
}
```

If *number_cpu* is equal to 1 it works. But if it is higher then 1, the program goes into segmentation fault.

Comment: You can always use a debugger to find where exactly the segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: you call `strcat` on something which is not a null-terminated string

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and provide that as part of your question. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt sorry about that. I edited the post as you said

Comment: regarding:  `char name_cpu[8] = {0};` and `name_cpu[j] = array_letters[rand() % (sizeof(array_letters)-1)];`  'name_cpu[]` is 8 characters, however, the posted code is trying to insert a binary value, with range -1...26 into each of the first 3 characters and will do this 3 times, into the same first 3 characters.  If your looking for some  'random' values, just do it once and the first thing in `main()` should be initializing the random number generator with something like:  `#include <time.h>`  and `srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );`

Answer (score 1):

***answer to new edits to OP***

Edits to OP include initialization of variables addressing some instances of undefined behavior in original code, however buffer overflow problem remains in following section:

```
/* Generator data */
  for(i = 0; i < number_cpu; i++)
  { 
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      name_cpu[j] = array_letters[rand() % (sizeof(array_letters)-1)];
      array_numbers_final[j] = array_numbers[rand() % (sizeof(array_numbers)-1)];
  }
   strcat(name_cpu, array_numbers_final);
   fprintf(list_cpu, "%s \n", name_cpu);
  }
  fclose(list_cpu);
```

Where `name_cpu` is defined with 8 char: `char name_cpu[8] = {0}`

> *"If number_cpu is equal to 1 it works. But if it is higher then 1, the program goes into segmentation fault."...*

After first iteration of outer loop, including one `strcat` of `name_cpu` and `list_cpu`, the `char name_cpu` is populated with 6 new characters and `\0` in remaining locations.  Eg:

```
//example
|S|J|P|Y|E|P|\0|\0|  //
```

The error occurs at end of 2nd iteration of outer loop at the `strcat()` statement.  The inner loop re-populated the first three positions of `name_cpu`, eg:

```
//first three positions changed, the rest remains
|C|B|A|Y|E|P|\0|\0|  // 
 ^ ^ ^ updated values
```

Error occurs when the new value for `array_numbers_final` :

```
|G|H|O|\0|\0|\0|\0|\0|
```

is attempted to be concatenated to `name_cpu`, resulting in:

```
|C|B|A|Y|E|P|G|H|O|  //attempt to write to memory not owned
                ^end of buffer
```

Resulting in buffer overflow error, and likely the *segmentation fault* error condition.
Again, as before, design variables to meet the potential needs of of the program.  In this instance the following will work:

```
 char name_cpu[100] = {0};
 char array_numbers_final[100] = {0};
```

***answer to original post***:
The problem is here:

```
strcat(name_cpu, array_numbers_final);//undefined behavior.
```

First, `name_cpu[8]` is uninitialized at time of declaration, nor is it initialized at any time before used.  Because it is not guaranteed what the contents are, it is not necessarily a string.  Using this variable as is in any string function can invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Furthermore,(even if `name_cpu` is a valid string) when `array_numbers_final` is concatenated to `name_cpu`,  the buffer will overflow.  During my test run I saw this:

[image]

The fix is to start off with initialized buffers of sufficient size for intended purpose.  eg:

```
 char name_cpu[100] = {0}
 array_numbers_final[100] = {0},    
 array_letters[27] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYVZ",
 array_numbers[10] = "123456789";
```

Code example below is adaptation using your provided example, with suggested edits.  Read in-line comments:

```
int main(void)
{
    int number_cpu = 3;//added - previously not defined in OP
    int i = 0,          
    j = 0;     
    char name_cpu[100] = {0},//resized and initialize
     array_numbers_final[100] = {0},//resized and initialize    
     array_letters[27] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYVZ",
     array_numbers[10] = "123456789";


/* Generator data */
      for(i = 0; i < number_cpu; i++)
      { 
          for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
          name_cpu[j] = array_letters[rand() % (sizeof(array_letters)-1)];
          array_numbers_final[j] = array_numbers[rand() % (sizeof(array_numbers)-1)];
        }

        strcat(name_cpu, array_numbers_final);
        fprintf(stdout, "%s \n", name_cpu);//to stdout
        //        ^ changed here
      }
    return 0;
}
```